# Swift. Краш приложения при встрече русского алфавита в ссылке

Tags: swift, url, swift3

Информация подтягивается с сайта в формате json, в котором содержится URL картинки, работает все замечательно, до момента, когда в URL встречаются русские буквы. Приложение останавливается выдавая ошибку:

> Thread 1: Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value

Код:

```
func loadImageUsingUrlString(urlString: String){
    imageUrlString = urlString
    let imageURL: URL = URL(string: imageUrlString!)!

    image = nil

    if let imageFromCache = imageCache.object(forKey: urlString as NSString) as? UIImage {
        self.image = imageFromCache
        return
    }
    URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: imageURL) { data, response, error in
        if error != nil{
            print(error)
            return
        }
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            guard let data = data, error == nil else { return }
            let imageToCache = UIImage(data: data)
            if self.imageUrlString == urlString{
                self.image = imageToCache
            }

            imageCache.setObject(imageToCache!, forKey: urlString as NSString)
               self.image = imageToCache
            }
        }.resume()
    }
)
```

Пример url: [http://heroine.lc/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/13/мини-300x209.png](http://heroine.lc/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/13/%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8-300x209.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Никогда не используйте в подобных случаях force unwrap.
А проблема в кодировке. Попробуйте по примеру:

```
let urlString = "http://heroine.lc/wp-content/uploads/2017/10/13/мини-300x209.png" //строка с адресом
if let urlString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlHostAllowed),
    let url = URL(string: urlString) {
    print(url) //если получили url из строки.
}
```

Comment: Кодировка действительно помогла, спасибо за помощь!!!